# How to add users to RHEL 7 Atomic Base Container Image?

Tags: docker, rhel7, containers

How do you add users to RHEL 7 atomic for Docker?

I am trying to containerize Elastic Stack on RHEL 7 atomic base image using Docker. I am able to install Elastic Search and its dependencies, but Elastic cannot be ran as root. Adduser does not seem to be supported, so I can add users to RHEL7 atomic. Is this a limitation or is there a way to run non root programs on RHEL 7 atomic?

Comment: no im running containers on RHEL 7 Server.. NOT RHEL 7 Atomic Host.. (yet) but I am trying to use the RHEL 7 atomic base image... as its a minimal base os image.. just trying to figure out how to add users.. doesnt seem to be a whole lot of documentation.

https://rhelblog.redhat.com/2017/03/13/introducing-the-red-hat-enterprise-linux-atomic-base-image/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create a user after adding the `shadow-utils` package, which contains `adduser`.

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7-atomic
RUN microdnf --enablerepo=rhel-7-server-rpms install shadow-utils ;\
    adduser elastic
USER elastic
```

As noted in the [article](https://rhelblog.redhat.com/2017/03/13/introducing-the-red-hat-enterprise-linux-atomic-base-image/) you linked, almost everything has been stripped out of this image.

BTW, unless you have a really strong overriding reason, you probably should just [use elasticsearch's own Docker images](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html).

Comment: thanks, this works.. I am required to stick with RHEL for my environment..

Comment: @emvee Well, maybe you can borrow their Dockerfiles anyway.